# Full Screen Notification That locks all other UI functionality until user reacts to notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

We're writing an app that gets events and needs to display a notification about the event in a very noticeable manner to the user. the notification should be like the in-coming call, i.e. full screen, lock all other activities of the same app till user reacts to the notification. the problem is that in the app there's an activity that launches automatically when a timer finishes. and we want to prevent that activity or any other activity to start on top of the notification.

`setFullScreenIntent()` doesn't give us full screen but a regular heads-up notification, so we tried to implement it by using an activity with flags like:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
```

but that didn't help either.

does anyone have an idea how to implement it? any code examples will be helpful.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that has anything to do with a notification.

Comment: `EventsDialog = new ....` What is `EventsDialog` ?

Comment: `setFlags()` will erase all earlier flags. So only the last call will have effect. `addFlags()` has to be called after `setFlags()`.

Comment: you are right, we didnt manage to imlement it by notification, so we tried instead to implement it by an activity with flags. we are looking for a good code example of full screen notification.

Comment: The flags anyways didnt give us the solution we are looking for, so we are looking for different solution...